# Simplify text processing pipeline with awk

Tags: awk, sed

I have the following text data (highly simplified):

```
dn: cn=config
objectClass: olcGlobal
cn: config
some: properties

dn: cn={0}kerberos,cn=schema,cn=config
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
cn: {0}kerberos
some: properties
some: junk
some: more junk

dn: olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
some: properties
```

The desired output is:

```
dn: cn=kerberos,cn=schema,cn=config
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
cn: kerberos
some: properties
```

I have written the following shell pipeline to achieve this:

```
awk -vRS= -vFS="\n" '/kerberos/{print $0}' /tmp/input.txt | \
    sed 's/{0}kerberos/kerberos/' | \
    sed '/some: junk/,$d'
```

This works just fine, but I feel like it's 'cheating' mixing awk and sed. How can I implement this using a single awk script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly, you only need one `sed` command, not two:

```
sed -e 's/{0}kerberos/kerberos/' -e '/some: junk/,$d'
```

Unless you insist on using a C shell, the backslashes at the ends of the lines are unnecessary.

You could do it all in a single `sed` command:

```
sed -n -e '/kerberos/,/^$/{
        s/{0}kerberos/kerberos/
        /some: junk/,$d; p;}'
```

which could be flattened onto a single line with a semicolon after the `s///` substitution.

```
sed -n -e '/kerberos/,/^$/{ s/{0}kerberos/kerberos/; /some: junk/,$d; p; }'
```

The semicolon before the `}` is needed with `sed` on Mac OS X (BSD); GNU `sed` is happy without it.

You can do it all in `awk` too:

```
awk '/kerberos/,/^$/ { sub(/\{0\}kerberos/,"kerberos");
                       if ($0 ~ /^some:/ && some++ > 0) next;
                       if ($0 != "") print
                     }' input.txt
```

which, for the input data, produces:

```
dn: cn=kerberos,cn=schema,cn=config
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
cn: kerberos
some: properties
```

Comment: your script worked fine for my sample input - the real data set (encountered in [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/kerberos-ldap.html#kerberos-ldap-openldap)) needed a slightly tighter match condition. Thanks for the awesome post, exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: This assume that after `some: ` you have  `junk`. I think that OP means just other data to delete. So here I would go for the `awk` not the `sed`